# add position to new entry in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am new to Ruby on Rails and want to do the following:

I have a list of user stories which is ordered by position using jQuery sortable. This all working great. The problem is that when I create a new userstory, position is set to nil. What I want to do is that a new user story is added to the button of the list. If though about the following:

1. find the user story with the highest number for position,
2. position new user story = position last one + 1

My controller looks like this:

```
def create
@userstory = Userstory.new(userstory_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @userstory.save
      format.html { redirect_to userstories_path, notice: 'Userstory was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
```

end

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [maximum](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#maximum) method to retrieve the maximum value of `position` field from database.

Add a `before_create` callback in `Userstory` model as below:

```
class Userstory < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_position ## Adding callback

  private    

  def set_position
    ## max_position will be set to maximum value of `position` field from userstories table
    ## max_position would be set as "nil" when userstories table is empty
    max_position = Userstory.maximum(:position) 
    self.position = max_position.nil? ? 1 : max_position+1
  end
end
```

**EXTRA POINTER:** Currently, your model name `Userstory` is not as per *Rails convention*. You should think about renaming it to `UserStory` and the concerned file name `user_story.rb` and lets not forget the table name as `user_stories`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @userstory = Userstory.new(userstory_params)
  @userstory.position = Userstory.order("position DESC").first.position + 1
  respond_to do |format|
    if @userstory.save
      format.html { redirect_to userstories_path, notice: 'Userstory was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

The above code should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback to your Userstore model

```
class Userstory < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_position

  private

  def set_position
    self.position = Userstory.any? ? Userstory.last.position : 1
  end
end
```